# How to install tar.gz package to Yocto by adding new layer?

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I new to Yocto so there are probably some mistakes and misunderstanding that I've had, I appreciate if you can help.

So, I want to add a new package (tar file) to my custom image.

I have followed steps and steps in manual and some online instructions. While running: "bitbake mylayer", the layer is built fine but I got this error while building the image, here is the log file:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function rootfs_deb_bad_recommendations
DEBUG: Python function rootfs_deb_bad_recommendations finished
DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['depmodwrapper-cross', 'apt-native', 'dpkg-native', 'pseudo-native', 'update-rc.d-native', 'prelink-native', 'makedevs-native', 'ldconfig-native', 'opkg-util$
DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_rootfs
NOTE: ###### Generate rootfs #######
NOTE: Installing the following packages: apt busybox copy-uefiimg-to-sda coreutils dpkg e2fsprogs-resize2fs libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libglib-2.0-0 gptfdisk libjemalloc2 kernel-module-axi-dma-sensor ku$
ERROR: Unable to install packages. 
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package mypackage is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mylayer' has no installation candidate

DEBUG: Python function do_rootfs finished
ERROR: Function failed: do_rootfs
```

And here is mylayer.bb:

```
SUMMARY = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSE"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://mypackage.tar"
```

Also, I have included the package in conf/local.conf:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " mylayer"
```

So beside trying to figure out how to solve this problem, I also have some questions:

1. I have read some example of .bb, and they mentioned about LIC_FILES_CHKSUM. The mypackage.tar.gz is a package to install a platform for the device and I don't know much about the source code, so I don't know if it is necessary to include the license? Or how to know that this package need license to install?
2. In some answer I found online, there is one saying that I need to include `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"` (they want to install the .deb file), so probably in my case I will need `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package.tar"` right? I have tried to change variable, but it still not successful.
3. The mypackage.tar includes some deb files. If I could not install mypackage.tar, can I instead install these .deb files? Can I put it all in mylayer.bb?

Thank you in advanced, I have tried to study much documents as I could but I get so confused and there is huge amount of information to digest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, before answering your questions

Let me mention some best practices advice for you:

Rename the recipe to some significant name related to you compressed package.

Naming the recipe to `mylayer` confuses Yocto users, because there is the term `layer` also.

**Regarding you recipe:**

There is no need for `FILESEXTRAPATHS` because the recipe path is added automatically to Yocto paths.

`FILESEXTRAPATHS` it is required for `.bbappend` files.

You need to override the `do_install` task function, it does nothing by default.

`do_install` is the first essential task to make sure that your sources are included in the final image.

Beside that, when specifying a compressed source file into `SRC_URI`, yocto automatically decompresses it.

This is mentioned [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SRC_URI).

So, here what your recipe should look like:

```
SUMMARY = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

# Prevent Yocto from decompressing the file
SRC_URI = "file://mypackage.tar;unpack=0"

do_install(){
    # Create the opt folder into the final image, ${D} is ${WORKDIR}/image
    install -d ${D}/opt
    # Copy the compressed file there; You can change permissions as you want
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/mypackage.tar ${D}/opt
}

# Very important to specify what you installed in (do_install)
FILES_${PN} = "/opt/*"
```

Now, when you run `IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " mylayer"` your file will be installed.

**Regarding your questions:**

1. You mentioned that your compressed file contains `.deb` files, I assume that no license checksum is needed. Also, I understand that you may wanted to point to `SRC_URI[md5sum]` or other checksums for the full package. That is also not needed for local files, it is used to check for the integrity of online sources.
2. `PACKAGE_CLASSES` as mentioned [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PACKAGE_CLASSES), is used by the system to know in what type the data should be packaged. By `the data` I mean the data that you installed with `do_install`. That data get packaged for according to your `PACKAGE_CLASSES` variable, for example, to `deb` file. And that is used, along side with all other recipes packages, to build the final rootfs.
3. Yes, if you are installing the `tar` file into the image and then unpack it to install all `deb` files, for example, with `dpkg`. You can use the `bin_package` class to do that, now the recipe must be changed for that reason:

- Decompress the `tar` file and provide the `deb` files in the local `files` folder.
- Add all `deb` files to `SRC_URI`
- Inherit the `bin_package` class
- Specify the files to be packaged.

Your recipe should look like this:

```
SUMMARY = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://deb_file1.deb \
       file://deb_file2.deb"

# No need to `do_install` , it is invoked by the (bin_package) class

FILES_${PN} = ""
```

**Important:**

About `FILES_${PN}`, you need to add all what the deb installed into the image folder

Example, if your deb file installs this:

```
/usr/bin/hello
/etc/hello.cfg
```

Specify them:

```
FILES_${PN} = "/usr/bin/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/*"
```

Use `*` so if other `deb` files install files into the same folder as others it will include all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I did what you've written and the package has been installed into the image! There is still one warning that appear and I don't really understand : `do_rootfs: The license listed BSD-3c was not in the licenses collected for the recipe libubox.` Is there any way to get rid of this warning? Or it's not important?

Comment: `if you are installing the tar file into the image and then unpack it to install all deb files, for example, with dpkg`
I think this will be my next step, and I'd like to ask if what I think is right: if I'll follow your instruction for question number 3, so I will be able to install the `deb` file directly to the image without have to run `dpkg` for each `deb` file?

Comment: So there is still 1 question that I have problem with: these deb files actually depends on each other to be installed, for example `file_deb1.deb` needed to be installed before `file_deb2.deb`. If I write the right order for `SRC_URI`, will these files be installed in order? Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't think that they are installed in order. You can check the source of the class: https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/classes/bin_package.bbclass , I think it checks all the content of `${S}` where the files are and installs them. It may be ordered alphabetically. You can test it

Comment: I have rebuild the package but got the error: `Error do_unpack: Unpack failure for URL: ´file://file_deb1.deb´. Error: do_unpack. Function failed: base_do_unpack` Do you know what possibilities that I've done wrong? I have added `inherit bin_package` and more folder to `FILES_${PN}`.